# Large table load slow mysql php high resources usage

Tags: mysql, php

in this situation i want to tell you guy's about one weird think.
Maybe its already answered for this but seriously i can't find answer.
I have table who have 130k records. 3 columns (id, product_id, picture_url).
When im creating SELECT picture_url FROM table WHERE id='1', server cpu,ram and ssd is going to 100% but when im selecting all SELECT * FROM table; Its loads fast and without any resourses usage. Where could be a problem for this weird situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check indexes and table structure

for 99% id - is INT
so

```
SELECT picture_url FROM table WHERE id='1'
```

born scan of all column and convert it to archer, same if no indexes - it start scan all table and sort

at the same time

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

just start send data without transformation

if I right - just change query for

```
SELECT picture_url FROM table WHERE id=1
```

and add index if it not already there

Comment: Yes one fail i have in id (i mean product_id) i was set up varchar not int i dont know why i change it and set index and now site is flying. I did it previous but it didnt have result, but i think this is answer. All works well for now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

If this is a many:many table for "mapping" products and pictures, do not include an id; instead use `PRIMARY KEY(procuct_id, picture_url)`.

See [*more tips on many:many*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).